# Pulling JSON data from external file with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables, each

I am currently pulling in JSON manually to test with a bootstrap table, but need to be able to pull from an external file, similar to how I was doing here:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#content').dataTable( {
            "ajax": 'test.log'
        });
    });
```

I'm currently manually setting data and looping through it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = [{"data":{
        "Account": "1234",
            "Domain": "domain.com",
        "PlayerClass": "Player"},
        "level": "info",
        "message": "",
        "timestamp": "2015-06-11T15:11:03.425Z"
    },
               {"data":{
        "Account": "4567",
            "Domain": "domain.com",
        "PlayerClass": "Player"},
        "level": "info",
        "message": "",
        "timestamp": "2015-06-11T15:11:03.425Z"
    }];
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data.Account + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].data.Domain + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].timestamp + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
});
```

Obviously the previous use of ajax was applying DataTables, so I either need to write it to just apply an `.each()` loop, or throw it into a DataTable.

Current version in **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/orhLtkj0/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to load the data in the format shown above would be to use the following DataTables initialization options:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "test.log",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data" : "data.Account" },
        { "data" : "data.Domain" },
        { "data" : "timestamp" }
    ]
});
```

Since you're using [Objects](http://datatables.net/manual/data#Objects) in your data, therefore you need to match object properties to table columns using [columns.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data). It possible to use dotted notation (for example, `data.Account`) to refer to object properties.

Also, [ajax.dataSrc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option is set to empty string to indicate that your JSON data is an array of data.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fnmzg8z/) for demonstration. Please note, that example uses `mockjax` library to simulate loading of the JSON file via Ajax for demonstration purposes only. Use URL to your actual file in `url` option.

Comment: This is going in the right direction, but I need to be able to load the json from a file, not hard coded into `responseText`.

Comment: @Matt,  JSFiddle example uses `mockjax` library to simulate loading of the JSON file via Ajax for demonstration purposes only. Use URL to your actual file in `url` option.

Comment: I have it working now, but its oddly adding blank rows with each row in the json, when called like so: 
"ajax": "test.log",
                "columns": [``
                 { "data" : "Account" },
                { "data" : "Domain" }
                 ]

Comment: @Matt, see my answer again about using dotted notation such as `data.Account` and `data.Domain` and not `Account` and `Domain`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but no data loads and I get the error: `DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'data.Account' for row 0.`

Comment: @Matt, then your data must be different from what you've posted in your question.

Comment: My test json is: 
`{
    "data": [
        {
            "Account": "2423",
            "Domain": "domain.com",
            "PlayerClass": "player"
        },
        {
            "level": "info",
            "message": "tag generator ",
            "timestamp": "2015-06-11T17:12:35.577Z"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: @Matt, Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80317/discussion-between-gyrocode-com-and-matt).